# How to import external sqlite database in android application for login?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I had created a login layout, but i need that the login id mustbe inbuilt that is externally created in sqlite database for login id and password.
How can i create that and how is that possible?
I had copied my database in assets folder & used databasehelper but still its not working.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: From the `assets` folder, it must be copied to either the storage or to the `/data/data/...` path. You can't just leave it in `assets` and pretend to use it.

Comment: @DerGolem i didn't just copied that but also used the code for the storage using the path for that. bt its still not working.

Comment: private static String DB_PATH = "//data/data/com.example.p2pmanager/databases/mydatabase";

Comment: `"//data/...` you put **2** slashes. It should be **1**, so: `"/data/...`  and the path name should not include the db name, if you then specify it. OR include the file extension, if present.

Comment: @DerGolem ok, i got that. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assets database file will only be a read-only file, you need to copy the DB file to your path. You can use below code to copy database file :

```
public void copyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException
{
    File myDir = getFilesDir();
    File dbFolder = new File(myDir, "database");
    if (!dbFolder.exists())
    {
        dbFolder.mkdirs();
    }
    String outFileName = dbFolder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "abc_db.sqlite";
    File file = new File(outFileName);
    if (file.exists())
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "db already exists");
        return;
    }
    InputStream myInput = getAssets().open("abc_db.sqlite");

    // Path to the just created empty db

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
    Log.e(TAG, "copy done");
}
```

After copying the file use file path to get data from database.

**EDITED :**

Change DB path to :

```
File myDir = getFilesDir();
File dbFolder = new File(myDir, "database");
String outFileName = dbFolder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "abc_db.sqlite";
File file = new File(outFileName);
String DB_PATH = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Did you changed the Database path in your DatabaseHelper class constructor?

Comment: yes i did, private static String DB_PATH = "//data/data/com.example.p2pmanager/databases/mydatabase";